# Return specific value from nested object javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is the object,

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 49472,
        "items": [
            {
                "hello": "james",
                "title": "game",
                "player": "123",
                "home": "syd",

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get a specific value from `player` and return `123` in the object using javascript. I have tried looking at other posts but I can't get it to work for my case.

I have managed to do this in python using the code below but it's not as simple to me with js.

```
for items in obj['response']['items']:
        print(items['player'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var myObject = {
    "response": {
        "count": 49472,
        "items": [
            {
                "hello": "james",
                "title": "game",
                "player": "123",
                "home": "syd"
            }
        ]
    }
};

myObject.response.items.forEach((v) => {
  console.log(v.player)
});
 // or
 
 myObject.response.items.map(res => console.log(res.player))
 
  // or
  
   console.log(myObject.response.items[0].player)
   //or
   
   console.log(myObject.response.items[0]['player'])
```

Comment: hey just wondering is it possible to turn the forEach code into a for loop doing the same thing. Just so its easier to use the value later.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = var t = {
    "response": {
        "count": 49472,
        "items": [
            {
                "hello": "james",
                "title": "game",
                "player": "123",
                "home": "syd",

            }
        ]
    }
}

t.response.items[0].player
"123"
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an `object` with an `object` which contains an `array` which contains an `object`.
You can access it like so: `myObject.response.items[0].player`

(Run the code snippet to see the result)

```js
var myObject = {
    "response": {
        "count": 49472,
        "items": [
            {
                "hello": "james",
                "title": "game",
                "player": "123",
                "home": "syd"
            }
        ]
    }
};

console.log(myObject.response.items[0].player);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you I was trying different versions of this and I must have got something basic wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like this:

```
response.items.forEach(item =>
    console.log(item.player)
)
```